# use a callback as a parameter

Tags: c++, opengl

I have the following class:

```
class Timer
{
public:
    Timer(){};
    ~Timer(){};

    void timer(int);
    //...

private:
    //...
};
```

My function timer(int value) is a callback that I use in glutTimerFunc(), inside the function timer(int value) i need to use the function timer again, something like this:

```
void Timer::timer(int value)
{
    //...

    glutTimerFunc(state->getTimer(), this->timer, 0);
}
```

How can i do it without using a static function?

Comment: you can't; glut is stupid that way that it doesn't add a `void* user` to its callbacks.

Comment: You can use a lambda to wrap the function call. This way you're passing glut a non-class method, but you're still calling your class method.

Comment: In C it is possible, in C++ if the callback is a `class` member function then it will not be easy. First `void timer(int)` must be `static` and then you need to do pass it like `&Timer::timer`.

Comment: @Ben is that C++11 specific?

Comment: @ratchetfreak it is not related to glut being stupid.

Comment: @iharob I believe so.

Comment: @iharob any library that requires you to rely on globals to pass state to callbacks is stupid.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need a global dispatcher that turns the `int` passed to `glutTimerFunc` into a c++ callback (member function, lambda, etc)

something like this

```
struct timer_dispatch
{
  using callback_t = std::function<void()>;

  int start_timer(int msecs, callback_t callback) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    int ident = _next_id++;
    _callbacks.emplace(ident, std::move(callback));
    glutTimerFunc(msecs, &timer_dispatch::dispatch_timer, ident);
    return ident;
  }

  // implement similar function for stop timer - don't forget the mutex
  void stop_timer(int ident) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
    _callbacks.erase(ident);
  }

  static timer_dispatch& instance() {
    static timer_dispatch _;
    return _;
  }  

private:
  // private constructor ensures use via the instance() static method;
  timer_dispatch() = default; 
  static void dispatch_timer(int ident) {
    auto self = instance();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(self._mutex);
    auto it = self._callbacks.find(ident);
    if (it != self._callbacks.end()) {
      auto my_copy = std::move(it->second);
      self._callbacks.erase(it);
      lock.unlock();
      my_copy();
    }
  }

private:      
  std::unordered_map<int, callback_t> _callbacks;
  std::mutex _mutex;
  int _next_id = 0;
};
```

now use like so:

```
// start my timer:
void myclass::start_alien() {
  ...
  _alien_timer_id = timer_dispatch::instance().start_timer(100, std::bind(&myclass::on_alien_timeout, this);
  ...
}

void myclass::on_alien_timeout() {
  // make alien do something, possibly restart a timer...
  _alien_timer_id = timer_dispatch::instance().start_timer(100, std::bind(&myclass::on_alien_timeout, this);
}

void myclass::on_alien_killed() {
  timer_dispatch::instance().stop_timer(_alien_timer_id);
  _alien_timer_id = -1;
}
```